# Validating the user role in a view asp mvc 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am conducting a validation role in this line of view

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"){}
```

or

```
@if (Role.IsUserInRole("Admin"){}
```

When I run it locally it works fine, but on the web this generates the following error:

> A  network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

[image: Here is a screenshot:]

I connect the database from my local server and it does not generate an error

I could give a hand, thanks

Comment: Can you connect to the database elsewhere in the application? Are all your connection strings working? If so, you are most likely missing a roleprovider related entry in your web.config

Comment: Correct the other queries work fine ... How should I use role provider?

Comment: `Role.IsUserInRole` is for membership. MVC5 doesn't use this.